# How to classify/detect outliers in simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model

Given a pair of training data set $(x,y)$, one can fit them into a linear model such that $y=x b + c$.

Given a new data pair $(x_i,y_i)$, how can I determine whether it is an outlier to the model $y=x b + c$ or not?

Answer (score 1):

If by outlier you mean something that falls $\pm2$ standard deviations from the prediction, you could simply see if $\frac{y-\hat{y_i}}{\sigma} > 2$.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to fit a model completely and there after check if a single new point is an outlier. You can only ask question like how well your model predicts $y_i$ when applied to  $x_i$. And look at things like $\sqrt{(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2}$ where $\hat{y_i}$ is the predicted $y_i$. Then you talk of root mean square errors not outliers. I am assuming $y_i$ is continuous.